# How to create MySQL field for date format input?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date

I have a select date field in my HTML form created using Javascript as follow:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top"><label for="received">Received Date:</label></td>
<td valign="top"><select id="daydropdown" name="rcvdy"></select>
<select id="monthdropdown" name="rcvmon"></select>
<select id="yeardropdown" name="rcvyr"></select> *</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to register the date input from the form into MySQL database. Do I need to create multiple field columns for each "day" "month" "year" input on my PHP file? Like this

```
$query=mysql_query('CREATE TABLE shiplog ( shpdy timestamp(2) NOT NULL, shmon timestamp(2) NOT NULL, shpyr timestamp(4) NOT NULL)')
```

Comment: HTML has nothing to do with your database structure! The PHP script in-between takes the submitted data and formats it for the database. Use *one* `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In html there's no need to create 3 separate select fields for day, month and year. Instead use an alternative like jquery UI DatePicker or something else. Then in table create a separate column Date(`DATE` type) and insert.
Jquery datepicker ui : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

P.S mysql DATE type is inserted in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I don't know why you would use a varchar for a date field, but I approve the rest of this message.

Comment: @John Blake Thank you so much for the info! It is a lot easier that way...Thanks again!

Comment: @Rhinosaurus: It all depends.varchar should be last lazy resort. If the date is only to display and no manipulations are done, i think its ok to put it in varchar.

Comment: @John Blake I used the JQuery datepicker() for the date field input. The database date column field is "input_date DATE NOT NULL". However when I tested input a data using the form and echoed the date $row['input_date'] the result: 000-00-00.

Comment: I solved it using this
list($year,$month,$day)=explode('/',$input_date);
$timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,$year,$month,$day);
$final_date=date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);

Comment: @hangee: While inserting the date into the table in what format did you insert. It should be Y-m-d ie 2013-05-30 . No harm in your explode solution but i think its addition of unnecessary lines of code.

Comment: @JohnBlake I guess so. You're really limiting what you can with with that field then. Seems just as easy to use a Date field and get all the functionality that comes with it not to mention drawbacks such as loss of proper sorting (and probably indexing). Seems like bad advice IMO.